# How can I forward all my iCloud emails to a Gmail address?

Tags: iphone, icloud, email, gmail

As the title of the question states, I would like to forward my iCloud email to my Gmail address. Specifically, I have an iCloud email that I made with my Apple ID as well as a Gmail address I made back in 2012 or something. Most of my emails go to my Gmail address, but I would still like to use my iCloud address for a few specific things. I know the easy answer is "go into your mail app and set up a filter to forward everything to your Gmail address," but the only Apple device I have is an iPhone and (as far as I can tell) you can't make filters from there.

*Given this information, how can I forward all my iCloud email to my Gmail address?*

Answer (score 7):

In [iCloud Mail](http://www.icloud.com), click the Action pop-up menu in the sidebar (as in the picture), then choose Preferences.

[image]

In the General pane, select `Forward my email to,` then type the forwarding address in the text field.

If you don’t want to store a copy of each forwarded message in iCloud, you can select: `Delete messages after forwarding.`

Keep in mind that storing copies of forwarded messages decreases your available iCloud storage space.

At the end clink: `Done`.